# Angle and circle intersection, find the circular segment area

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Playing Kerbal Space Program, I found myself wondering about what a satellite would see of a planet depending on its field of view and its altitude. I tried attacking the problem from various angles but I always end up with a missing piece of information.

Speaking a bit more formally, I have a circle **Planet** with a radius **r**. I have a point **Sat** which is at a distance **Orb** from the center of **Planet** (for our case, **Orb > r**). The line **Sat-Center(Planet)** bisects **A-Sat-B**, with **A** and **B** being points on the circle.

I know **Orb**, **r** and the angle **A-Sat-B**, what ways do I have to calculate **A-B**? (See below for a diagram.)

From there I think the [Circular segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) will let me find the information I need but I'm stumped on the calculation.

[image: Planet-Sat diagram]

Comment: Are you looking for the tangent points on a circle from an exterior point? If yes, there is geometric answer and an algebraic answer. What do you want?

Comment: No, not necessarily the tangents, because the angle **A-Sat-B** would then be determined easily. I don't know the angle, but A and B are not necessarily tangents points to **Planet**

Comment: What are **A** and **B** then? How are they defined? I am confused on what is known or not. Maybe a picture/sketch can help.

Comment: I've added a diagram to your question. If it's an incorrect interpretation of your question, please remove/edit it or ask for revisions.

Comment: Thanks @Semiclassical, I was in the process of making one diagram but yours is completely correct and much nicer (what tool did you use?)

Comment: Mathematica graphics + MS Paint. A bit laborious, but it works.

Comment: Next time download Geogebra and use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have the angle $\theta$, the planet radius $r$ and the orbital distance ${\rm Orb}$

[image: Pic]

the solution arrives from two trigonometry  equations:

$$ \left. 
\begin{aligned} {\rm Orb} & = r \cos \frac{\psi}{2} + \ell \cos \frac{\theta}{2} \\
 r \sin \frac{\psi}{2} & = \ell \sin \frac{\theta}{2} \end{aligned} 
\right\} 
\begin{aligned}  \frac{\psi}{2} & = \frac{\pi-\theta}{2} - \cos^{-1} \left(  \frac{{\rm Orb}}{r}\sin \frac{\theta}{2}\right) 
\end{aligned}
 $$

With $h = r \sin \frac{\psi}{2} $  and ${\bf AB} = 2 h$

For example, when $r=1$, ${\rm Orb}=3.5$ and $\theta=25°$ then

[image: Pic2]

$$ \frac{\psi}{2} = \frac{180°-25°}{2} - \cos^{-1} \left(  \frac{3.5}{1}\sin \frac{25°}{2}\right) =  36.74768°$$  which is same as measured $\beta$ angle in diagram above.

Then $h = 1 \sin (36.74768°) = 0.5982922 $ which also matches diagram above.

Also we can check $\ell = \frac{ r \sin \frac{\psi}{2} }{\sin\frac{\theta}{2}} = { r \sin(0.6413681) }{\sin(12.5°)} = 2.764245$

Diagram is made with [GeoGebra 4](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/en/download/)

Comment: Don't look.. I am fixing it

Comment: I looked what should I do?

Comment: I got a workable solution now and I am working on an example.

Comment: Ok .. please review answer now.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap y head around the jump from your two equations to the one you propose afterwards. In the meantime take a +1 :D

Comment: Yes, I left out some steps for brevity. Solve for $\ell$ on the second equation and use it in the first one. You end up with $$\frac{{\rm Orb}}{r} = \cot \alpha \sin \beta + \cos \beta$$

Comment: Which is further simplified as $$ \left. \frac{\rm Orb}{r} = \frac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{\sin(\alpha)} \right\}  \beta = \alpha + \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{\rm Orb}{r} \sin \alpha \right) $$

Comment: I'm just missing this last part: $$cot(\alpha)sin(\beta) + cos(\beta) = \frac{sin(\alpha+\beta)}{sin(\alpha)}$$ I couldn't find the way from left to right

Comment: $$\cot \alpha \sin \beta + \cos \beta =\frac{ \cos \alpha \sin \beta}{\sin \alpha} + \cos \beta = \frac{\cos \alpha \sin \beta + \sin \alpha \cos \beta}{\sin \alpha}$$

Comment: Obvious in hindsight, but I missed it completely

Answer (score -2):

[image]

$\text{The answer can be as explained below -  }\\$

$\text{Join $A$ and $B$, Let $C$ be centre,}\\$
$\text{Now join $AC$ and $BC$, get $\theta$, the $\angle$ that lines $AC$ and $BC$ make at the centre,}\\$
$\text{find the length of the chord $AB$, which will be $\frac{1}{2}$ the $diameter$ if angle is $\frac {\pi}{2}$,}\\$
$\text{depending on the $\angle \theta $, whether it is $\pi$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$ respectively, and so on.}\\$

$\text{Now when you know $AB$,}\\$
$\text{You can also check (A-SAT) $or$ (SAT-B), by geometry finding the 2 equal}\\$
$\text{sides of a triangle by pythagorous theorem when base and height are known,}\\$
$\text{$or$ The Arc length $AB$ $=$ $r$ $\cdot$ $\theta$ & the }\\$
$$\text{$"Darkened Circular Segment Area"$} = \left[\frac {r^2}{2} \cdot \left(\frac{\pi \cdot \theta}{180} - \sin \theta \right)\right]$$